# How do I design the mobile interface for submitting a new "Conversation title", which is similar to submitting a Reddit post?

Tags: design, lists, android

So, each conversation is basically like a Reddit thread, where people can discuss chat in real time.

Right now I just have a basic design with a text box and a button right on the bottom of the screen. I updated the button to be a Floating Action Button, but I don't exactly know how to redesign the process of adding a new conversation title.

Should the button pop up a dialog bar where user can put the title and then click submit? Should the icon lead to a new screen (Activity)? Any other ideas? What's a cool way?

[image: App screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

When the user presses the button, **add a new item to the list** with a text field instead of the title.

Ensure that the keyboard is displayed and **focus is automatically set to the text field**, so the user can immediately start typing their title.

You should also ensure that the new item is **above the keyboard**.

---

This is how the Apple's Reminders app works, albeit for a simpler purpose:

[image: iOS Reminders new reminder]

Comment: That actually sounds very interesting! Thanks! Do you think that would be a better experience compared to how the official Reddit app works when submitting a new post, or how the Slack app works when creating a new channel?

Comment: If the title is the only piece of information you must provide to create a conversation, then the method I describe would be best. However, if the user must provide other information then opening an activity (as I believe Reddit/Slack do; correct me if I'm wrong) would be better. If the user is very likely to immediately enter other optional fields, displaying these fields in the activity would also be beneficial.